# How to lock node for deletion process

Tags: alfresco

Within alfresco, I want to delete a node but I don't want to be used by any other users in a cluster environment.

I know that I will use LockService for lock a node (in a cluster environment) as in the folloing lines:

```
lockService.lock(deleteNode);
nodeService.deleteNode(deleteNode);
lockService.unlock(deleteNode);
```

the last line may cause an exception because the node has already been deleted, and indeed it causes the exception is

> A system error happened during the operation: Node does not exist: workspace://SpacesStore/cb6473ed-1f0c-4fa3-bfdf-8f0bc86f3a12

So how to ensure concurrency in a cluster environment when delete a node to prevent two users to access the same node at the same time one of them want to update it and the second once want o delete it?

Comment: I think There is no need for lock a node i the node going to be deleted, this answer based on alfresco code itself.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your cluster environment (e.g. same DB server used by all Alfresco instances), transactions might most likely just be enough to ensure no stale content is used:

```
serverA(readNode)
serverB(deleteNode)
serverA(updateNode) <--- transaction failure
```

The [`JobLockService`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/repo/lock/JobLockService.html) allows more control in case of more complex operations, which might involve multiple, dynamic nodes (or no nodes at all, e.g. sending emails or similar):

```
serverA(acquireLock)
serverB(acquireLock) <--- wait for the lock to be released
serverA(readNode1)
serverA(if something then updateNode2)
serverA(updateNode1)
serverA(releaseLock)
serverB(readNode2)
serverB(releaseLock)
```

Comment: Can you please give me an example about JobLockService ?

Comment: Skuro, still i'm confused in JobLockService, JobLockService does not acquire a lock in the node it is lock the QName !!

Comment: that's exactly the point: you don't lock on a node, you lock on a QName. It's a more generic locking, more similar to a `synchronized` Java block than a lock on a node. Every time you use the same `QName` to acquire a JobLock you will synchronize on the same lock.

Comment: If i understand you correctly then when i'm talking about lock QName i talk about lock nodes rather lock a node, and as example JobLockService.getLock("{URI}content"); Then all nodes from type cm:content and its child in the inheritance structure will be locked until the operation being started finished. correct me skuro you mean that ? What exactly will be locked if we know that QName is a representation for property, association, aspect and type.

Comment: or you talk about lock on QName as "keys" in the synchronized blocks ! that is synchronized(QName) will means QName here will be a key for synchronization blocks will prevents any threads access the same block at the same time even we use a cluster environment

Comment: In the latest comment I think you got it right: the `QName` you use in `JobLockService` operations *is not related* to your content model. It's rather a symbolic ID for an operation or "job". Then you can use them to control concurrency of certain actions, even in clustered environments.

Comment: An exception  has been thrown once i use JobLockService ! How to  use it ? even though i write code identical to the code in the AbstractNodeCleanupWorker class which located into the internet

Comment: Exception is a NullPointerException ! even i create a QName from QName.create(URI,localname)

Comment: I fix it, i think the lock is acquired :) Thanks Skuro